# Are there any active mods here? I asked for help with deleting my account and got no response

Tags: support, user-accounts

I requested my profile deletion a couple of **months** ago and I haven't received any response from staff. I've tried through "other topic" and no response. Is there any reason not to let me delete my profile here?

Comment: I'm afraid site moderators can't do anything about that. We're just regular users, like you, with a few more buttons to click. This isn't one of them. Please follow the instructions in the answer below. That said, Stack Exchange employees also monitor meta sites, so there might be an update coming from them soon.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment, mods can actually delete accounts, I meant we don't receive the deletion requests you have sent SE which is why we hadn't done anything about it.

Answer (score 10):

To delete your account just follow [How do I delete my account?](https://askubuntu.com/help/deleting-account), essentially:

[image]

While it's strange nobody answered in fact it's not at all necessary to contact the probably busy mods for an account deletion.

Answer (score 9):

You've contacted us 4 times over the past 13 months. Each time, we've responded with instructions on how to delete your account. Each time, we've gotten no response until the *next* time you contacted us.

[image: list of closed tickets]

My guess is that you spam-blocked all of our responses. Makes it kinda hard to help you, y'know?

Anyway, I'm glad you finally asked here - as your profile indicates, you *were* able read dessert's helpful response and thus finally able to schedule your profile for deletion.

So long, and thanks for all the <s>fish</s> tickets...

Comment: Good day. First, **you don't need to be ironic** for help. I'm a top user of StackOverflow in Spanish, so, I put voluntarily my time and effort to make the community bigger, so, you don't need to treat me with irony. Second, I didn't receive any email (that's obvious, I think). Thrid, thanks for attend my petition. Adiós.

Comment: I don't think there's anything ironic here; please do check your spam folder & whitelist the SO reply address.